# OpenXML : replacing text in multiples runs

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I have a word document with fields that I need to change (see below) but for a reason that I don't understand, my modification is not saved during the process.

I'm using the OpenXML .NET SDK in C#.
Code :

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    var body = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    foreach (var headerParts in myDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
    {
        foreach (var Para in headerParts.Header.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>())
        {
            foreach (var run in Para.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run>())
            {
                foreach (var text in run.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
                {
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace("Nom", cv.firstName);
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace("Prenom", cv.secondName);
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace("NbAnnee", cv.nbAnneeExp.ToString());
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace("Objet", cv.objet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

I don't know where I'm wrong, I followed a lot of templates that were present on SO.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure the strings you are trying to replace are correct? Is is possible to upload your source file somewhere?

Comment: Found it meanwhile, I used a content control and this is why it didn't work : these controllers can't be editable so I used a workaround with InnerXML :/.

Comment: But  thank you for your help anyway @petelids . If you have time, do you have any answer for this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701541/openxml-net-replace-text-in-control-content

Answer (score 0):

So I found myself the answer : In fact, in my document, I add content controller and because there are not editable, the changement could not be saved during the process.

Morality : this method works... only if you don't use content controller :D