# Replace text in control content

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I have a word template that I need to change insering some text at some precise spots.

I already done an header but I used only the InnerXML and I can try to not use this function it could be better.

My code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    var mainDocumentPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    //Body
    var body = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    List<SdtElement> SdtBlocks = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>().ToList();

    //var text = SdtBlocks[0].Descendants<Text>().First().Text;
    //SdtBlocks[0].Descendants<Text>().First().Text.Replace(SdtBlocks[0].InnerText, cv.Resume);

    foreach (var element in SdtBlocks)
    {
        if (element.InnerText.Contains("Resume"))
        {
            element.Descendants<Text>().First().Text = cv.Resume;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(element.Descendants<Text>().First().Text);
        }
        //foreach(var text in element.Descendants<Text>())
        //{
        //}
    }
```

cv is my objet with my data.

So actually, doing this doesn't change the part containing "Resume" on my final word.
Also, I will have some list to add on this word and I don't know how to. I tried to find some info on the internet and on openXML related site (including the one of Eric White) but I couldn't find the solution.

Any idea and to fix this and also for the second part ?

***EDIT*** : So I finally fixed the 1st part thanks to @petedelis :

```
var text = SdtBlocks[0].Descendants<Text>().First().Text;
Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
Run newRun = new Run();
Text newText = new Text(cv.Resume);
newRun.Append(newText);
newParagraph.Append(newRun);
SdtBlocks[0].Parent.InsertBefore(newParagraph, SdtBlocks[0]);
SdtBlocks[0].Remove();
```

Now I am on the table part : My table looks like this : [image: Image of the template]

I need to duplicate the second row for each mission. Actually I have this :

```
foreach (Mission mission in listeMission)
                {
                    SdtRow newRow = new SdtRow();
                    SdtContentRow newContent = new SdtContentRow();
                    newParagraph = new Paragraph();
                    newRun = new Run();
                    Text cell = new Text(mission.Titre);
                    newRun.Append(cell);
                    newParagraph.Append(newRun);
                    newContent.Append(newParagraph);
                    newRow.Append(newContent);
                    rowTemplate.RemoveAllChildren();
                    rowTemplate.Append(newContent);
                    rowTemplate.Parent.InsertBeforeSelf(newRow);
}
```

But the result is not what I want. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what your issue is here but does [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099130/3791802) help at all?

Comment: For the Resume it did help ! Thank you ! :D
Now I need to understand the table part,
Gonna edit the question

Comment: Edited, do you have an idea ? @petelids

Comment: What do you mean by "*this is not running*" ? do you get any error message or... ? Could you show what you get vs what you want ?

Comment: Nono but this is not what I want (I did not express myself correctly, gonna edit). But I want rows like the template one

Comment: Edited @Rafalon

Comment: And so what are the differences between the result and what you want ? Can you show us the result ?

Comment: Here you are : [link](https://puu.sh/ws76c/7717f5b4df.png)
As you can see, the new phrase added is under the table and I want to have something like this : [link](https://puu.sh/ws7aT/a3c73a942d.png) @Rafalon

Comment: When/where is your `rowTemplate` initialized ?

Comment: Before, `// Find the first table in the document.
                    Table table = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().Skip(1).First();

                    // Find the second row in the table.
                    SdtRow rowTemplate = table.Elements<SdtRow>().First();` @Rafalon

Comment: `rowTemplate.Parent.InsertBeforeSelf(newRow);` doesn't quite look right to me - you don't want to insert it before the table, you want to insert it at the end of the table. I'd try changing that line to `rowTemplate.Parent.Append(newRow);`

Answer (score 0):

You say you are finding the first table in the document, and then the second row of this table with this code :

```
// Find the first table in the document. 
Table table = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().Skip(‌​1).First(); 
// Find the second row in the table. 
SdtRow rowTemplate = table.Elements<SdtRow>().First();
```

I think you are in fact finding the second table in the document, and then the first row of this table with it.

Maybe try the following instead ?

```
// Find the first table in the document. 
Table table = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First(); 
// Find the second row in the table. 
SdtRow rowTemplate = table.Elements<SdtRow>().Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: On my document, this is my 1st table : 

https://puu.sh/ws89i/a359e3b37a.png

There is also a "table" before but for it is not a real one.
There error is "Sequence contains no elements", as expected